# How to display div with same ID and OnClick function - Javascript, HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and i've reached an issue I can't figure out yet, so I'll explain it as best as I can.

I've got 2 divs containing a reply link with the same ID, OnClick. Only difference is the data-attribute which I thought could be used to differentiate the two. There are 2 reply divs that are styled to be hidden. The aim is once the reply link is clicked, the correct div will display below it.

The issue is, when you click any of the two Reply links, it only opens the first reply div below the first parent div. I'll created a little example to give a better understanding:

```js
// Opens reply div and retrieves data-attribute (reply_id) to insert into MYSQL database
    function replyLink(element) {
      document.getElementById('reply').style.display = "block";
    }
    
    // Close div link, displays after opening reply box
    function closeLink() {
      document.getElementById('reply').style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
#comment{
            border: 1px solid #333333;
            width: 500px;
            height: 85px;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 10px 10px 15px 10px;
        }

        #comment #content{
            border: none;
            padding: 15px;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        #comment #link{
            border: none;
            padding: 5px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        #comment #link a{
            border: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: blue;
        }

        #comment #link a:hover{
            border: none;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: blue;
        }

        #reply{
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 0px 0px 10px 45px;
            width: 400px;
        }
```

```html
<div id="comment">

    <div id="content">
        Content #1
    </div>

    <div id="link">
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="replyLink()" data-test='1'>Reply</a>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="reply" style="display: none;">
        reply container 1
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='closeLink()' />[Close]</a>
    </div>

<div id="comment">

    <div id="content">
        Content #2
    </div>

    <div id="link">
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="replyLink()" data-test='2'>Reply</a>
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="reply" style="display: none;">
        reply container 2
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='closeLink()' />[Close]</a>
    </div>
```

Would a java genius be able to help me out.

Comment: ID's have to be unique. Using the same ID multiple times is invalid. Instead of fixing an issue caused by an invalid markup I would start fixing the invalid ID usages.

Comment: How would I make them unique? I'm pulling rows from a database in a while function, that's why I'm using data attributes. Also, the code snippet I gave is just a simplified version of the issue

Comment: first I would use classes for the links. Then you can use `for`-loops to pull the elements and use the index of the loop to add a number to the ID

Comment: Any chance you can edit the code snippet and show me what you mean? Fairly new to javascript

Comment: While the use of an `id` is straightforward when first working with JavaScript and HTML, it's use is discouraged as an anti-pattern. IDs make for brittle code (as you are seeing here) and don't scale well. Instead, don't use `id`s at all and instead use classes or a relative reference to the elements, such as `this`, `.closest()`, `nextElementSibling`, `parentNode`, etc.

Comment: Also, using hyperlinks as a "hook" to initiate some code upon a `click` event is semantically incorrect. Hyperlinks are for navigation and people who use screen readers will have difficulty navigating your page. Just about every visible HTML element supports a `click` event, so just attach a `click` handler directly to the element instead of wrapping the element with a hyperlink.

Comment: @ScottMarcus or use a `<button>` element as it a semantically correct element with accessibility features (like focus).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the classes for styling and IDs with indexes to identify the unique div boxes.
Here is the working example

```js
 function replyLink(index) {
      document.getElementById('reply_' + index).style.display = "block";
  }

  // Close div link, displays after opening reply box
  function closeLink(index) {
      document.getElementById('reply_' + index).style.display = "none";
  }
```

```css
 .comment {
      border: 1px solid #333333;
      width: 500px;
      height: 85px;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 10px 10px 15px 10px;
  }

  .comment .content {
      border: none;
      padding: 15px;
      font-size: 12px;
  }

  .comment .link {
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-top: 5px;
  }

  .comment .link a {
      border: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: blue;
  }

  .comment .link a:hover {
      border: none;
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: blue;
  }

  .reply {
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 0px 0px 10px 45px;
      width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="content">
            Content #1
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="replyLink(0)" data-test='1'>Reply</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reply" id="reply_0" style="display: none;">
        reply container 1
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='closeLink(0)'>[Close]</a>
    </div>

    <div class="comment">
        <div class="content">
            Content #2
        </div>
        <div class="link">
            <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick="replyLink(1)" data-test='2'>Reply</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="reply" id="reply_1" style="display: none;">
        reply container 2
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='closeLink(1)'>[Close]</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the use of an id is straightforward when first working with JavaScript and HTML, it's use is discouraged as an anti-pattern. IDs make for brittle code (as you are seeing here) and don't scale well. Instead, don't use ids at all and instead use classes or a relative reference to the elements, such as this, .closest(), nextElementSibling, parentNode, etc.

Also, using hyperlinks as a "hook" to initiate some code upon a click event is semantically incorrect. Hyperlinks are for navigation and people who use screen readers will have difficulty navigating your page. Just about every visible HTML element supports a click event, so just attach a click handler directly to the element instead of wrapping the element with a hyperlink.

Lastly, there is no need for separate show and hide functions. Just add or remove a "hidden" class based on what was clicked.

You can see in my answer how much cleaner the HTML and JavaScript are without `id`s.

See comments inline below.

```js
// Set up a single event handler for any clicks to any reply or Close
document.addEventListener("click", function(event){   

  // Check to see if the click originated at a Reply element
  if(event.target.classList.contains("reply")){
    // Find the closest ".comment" ancestor of the clicked reply
    // element and then get the next element sibling to that and
    // unhide it.
      event.target.closest(".comment")
        .nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else if(event.target.classList.contains("replyContainer")){
    event.target.classList.add("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
.comment{
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    width: 500px;
    height: 85px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 10px 15px 10px;
}

.comment .reply{
   padding: 5px;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

.replyContainer{
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding: 15px;
   margin: 0px 0px 10px 45px;
   width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
    <div class="content">Content #1</div>
    <div class="reply">Reply</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden replyContainer">reply container 1[Close]</div>

<div class="comment">
    <div class="content">Content #2</div>
    <div class="reply">Reply</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden replyContainer">reply container 2[Close]</div>

<div class="comment">
    <div class="content">Content #3</div>
    <div class="reply">Reply</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden replyContainer">reply container 3[Close]</div>
```